# unable to run crystal report on client machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have made a project in `vs2010` ,then i have created a setup project n deployed .when i run application on my PC it obviously runs well , but for client machine the application runs well except crystal reports.
i made setup project and then added prerequisites

```
Microsoft .Net framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)
 SQL server 2008 express
 windows installer 3.1
```

selected > download prerequisites from the same location as my application > ok

this way when i build project it is success and application runs well but without crytal report on client machine. So i tried to add prerequisite SAP crystal Report Runtime Engine for .Net framework 4.0 > ok

then it shows 4 errors on building setup project ,which are ;

```
Error   5   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0.msi' for item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework 4.0' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.

Error   7   General failure building bootstrapper   

Error   6   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0.msi' for item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework 4.0' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.

Error   8   Unrecoverable build error.
```

I tried installing CR runtime for .NET framework 4.0 on client PC but it gives error that `first install vs2010 to install CR runtime`.vs2010 should not be installed on client PC ,I don't know how to fix it  and where is the problem ,crystal reports are running well in my PC ,help me to run it on client PC .thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I somehow solved it , I have  changed the `property` of all reports `.rpt` files , set `build action` from `Embedded Resource` to `Content` and then copied all  `.rpt` and `.cs` files of my reports in the same `setup` folder , so it is running well on client machine too .

Comment: You don't need to place `.cs` file. you need to put only `.rpt` files.

Comment: yeah but not from project. you need to remove it from setup project. In short it is not require to have .cs file once the file build. Application needs only .rpt files where it has published.